# Python C extension: method signatures for documentation?

Tags: python, documentation, python-c-api

I am writing C extensions, and I'd like to make the signature of my methods visible for introspection.

```
static PyObject* foo(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {

    /* blabla [...] */

}

PyDoc_STRVAR(
    foo_doc,
    "Great example function\n"
    "Arguments: (timeout, flags=None)\n"
    "Doc blahblah doc doc doc.");

static PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    {"foo", foo, METH_VARARGS, foo_doc},
    {NULL},
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC init_myexample(void) {
    (void) Py_InitModule3("_myexample", methods, "a simple example module");
}
```

Now if (after building it...) I load the module and look at its help:

```
>>> import _myexample
>>> help(_myexample)
```

I will get:

```
Help on module _myexample:

NAME
    _myexample - a simple example module

FILE
    /path/to/module/_myexample.so

FUNCTIONS
    foo(...)
        Great example function
        Arguments: (timeout, flags=None)
        Doc blahblah doc doc doc.
```

I would like to be even more specific and be able to replace **foo(...)** by **foo(timeout, flags=None)**

Can I do this? How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My usual approach to finding out about things like this is: "use the source".

Basically, I would presume that the standard modules of python would use such a feature when available. Looking at the source ([for example here](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release26-maint/Modules/fcntlmodule.c?revision=72888&view=markup)) should help, but in fact even the standard modules add the prototype after the automatic output. Like this:

```
torsten@pulsar:~$ python2.6
>>> import fcntl
>>> help(fcntl.flock)
flock(...)
    flock(fd, operation)

    Perform the lock operation op on file descriptor fd.  See the Unix [...]
```

So as upstream is not using such a feature, I would assume it is not there. :-)

Okay, I just checked current python3k sources and this is still the case. That signature is generated in `pydoc.py` in the python sources here: [pydoc.py](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/pydoc.py?revision=73529&view=markup). Relevant excerpt starting in line 1260:

```
        if inspect.isfunction(object):
            args, varargs, varkw, defaults = inspect.getargspec(object)
            ...
        else:
            argspec = '(...)'
```

inspect.isfunction checks if the object the documentation is requested for is a Python function. But C implemented functions are considered builtins, therefore you will always get `name(...)` as the output.

Answer (score 20):

It has been 7 years **but you can include the signature for C-extension function and classes**.

Python itself uses the [Argument Clinic](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/clinic.html) to dynamically generate signatures. Then some mechanics create a `__text_signature__` and this can be introspected (for example with `help`). @MartijnPieters explained this process quite well in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25847066/5393381).

You may actually get the argument clinic from python and do it in a dynamic fashion but I prefer the manual way: Adding the signature to the docstring:

In your case:

```
PyDoc_STRVAR(
    foo_doc,
    "foo(timeout, flags=None, /)\n"
    "--\n"
    "\n"
    "Great example function\n"
    "Arguments: (timeout, flags=None)\n"
    "Doc blahblah doc doc doc.");
```

I made heavy use of this in my package: [`iteration_utilities/src`](https://github.com/MSeifert04/iteration_utilities/tree/master/src/iteration_utilities/_iteration_utilities). So to demonstrate that it works I use one of the C-extension functions exposed by this package:

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import minmax
>>> help(minmax)
Help on built-in function minmax in module iteration_utilities._cfuncs:

minmax(iterable, /, key, default)
    Computes the minimum and maximum values in one-pass using only
    ``1.5*len(iterable)`` comparisons. Recipe based on the snippet
    of Raymond Hettinger ([0]_) but significantly modified.

    Parameters
    ----------
    iterable : iterable
        The `iterable` for which to calculate the minimum and maximum.
[...]
```

The docstring for this function is defined [this file](https://github.com/MSeifert04/iteration_utilities/blob/v0.10.1/src/iteration_utilities/_iteration_utilities/docsfunctions.h).

It is important to realize that this **isn't possible for python < 3.4** and you need to follow some rules:

- You need to include `--\n\n` after the signature definition line.
- The signature must be in the first line of the docstring.
- The signature must be valid, i.e. `foo(a, b=1, c)` fails because it's not possible to define positional arguments after arguments with default.
- You can only provide one signature. So it doesn't work if you use something like:

  ```
  foo(a)
  foo(x, a, b)
  --

  Narrative documentation
  ```

Comment: Sounds like a thing that `numpy` needs a patch for

Comment: This works. But what about type annotations? When I add them it no longer works.

Comment: I haven't worked with C extensions for a while. However a few years (2018) back that didn't work, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50763175/5393381. You might want to check if the referenced Python code did change in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

In case it is helpful, I have found that something like the following works to provide a type signature and also let PyCharm understand the typing.

For a function that should have the following signature (and where the second parameter is optional):

```
def function(paramA: str, paramB: bool = False) -> str:
```

I would use the following in the ml_doc field of PyMethodDef:

```
"function(paramA, /, paramB=False)\n--\nn"
"function(paramA: str, paramB: bool=False) -> str\n"
":param str paramA: blah blah blah\n"
":param str paramB: blah blah blah\n"
":returns: blah blah blah\n"
":rtype: str\n\n"
"some narrative description of the function"
```

Everything before the "\n--\n\n" is used by python to populate `__text_signature__` on the method. The rest goes into `__doc__`.  PyCharm parses `__doc__` to figure out the types.  The double newline at the end of the `:rtype:` line is necessary for PyCharm to process it correctly, otherwise the following description gets annexed to it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).