# What are __signature__ and __text_signature__ used for in Python 3.4

Tags: python, signature, python-3.4, python-internals

If one does `dir()` on some builtin callables (class constructors, methods, etc) on CPython 3.4, one finds out that many of them often have a special attribute called `__text_signature__`, for example:

```
>>> object.__text_signature__
'()'
>>> int.__text_signature__
>>> # was None
```

However the documentation for this is nonexistent. Furthermore, googling for the attribute name suggests that there is also another possible special attribute `__signature__`, though I did not find any built-in functions that would have it.

I do know they are related to the function argument signature, but nothing beyond that, what do their values signify and what is the use of them?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These attributes are there to enable introspection for Python objects defined in C code. The [C-API Argument Clinic](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/clinic.html) provides the data, to assist the `inspect` module when building [`Signature` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#introspecting-callables-with-the-signature-object). Introspection of C-API functions was not supported before.

See the internal [`inspect._signature_fromstr()` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9f220e4968cf73fa60440120ee46881e7974e47d/Lib/inspect.py#L1958-L2093) on how the `__text_signature__` value is used.

Currently, the `__text_signature__` attribute is filled from the internal docstring set on objects in the C-API; a simple text search is done for `objectname(...)\n--\n\n`, where the `\n--\n\n` is typical of Attribute Clinic-generated documentation strings. Take a look at the [`type` object slots](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9f220e4968cf73fa60440120ee46881e7974e47d/Objects/typeobject.c#L6933-L7118) if you wanted to find some examples. Or you could look at the [`audioop` module source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/45e4efba7fa2abe61d25e4f8b5bf482e19ff1280/Modules/audioop.c) to see how the Argument Clinic is being used to define signatures; the [Argument Clinic script](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d322abbb83eb751045246a70f39d040d13a6108b/Tools/clinic/clinic.py) is run on those when building to generate the docstrings (in the accompanying [`audioop.c.h` file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9f220e4968cf73fa60440120ee46881e7974e47d/Modules/clinic/audioop.c.h)).

The `__signature__` attribute, if present, would be a `inspect.Signature()` object; instead of providing a text version a C-API can provide a fully parsed `Signature` instance instead.

Comment: There is a grave error in your answer though, the C-API is called Argument Clinic, a reference to the Monty Python sketch by the same name ;)

Comment: @Antti: *I've told you once*.

Comment: The beginning still says "Attribute Clinic" :D

Comment: @Antti: *No it doesn't*. I'm sorry, is this a 5 minute argument or a full half hour?

Comment: oh... just the five minutes.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much for the [audioop](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/fcf45ec7863e/Modules/audioop.c) example! Very helpful.

Answer (score 18):

### Quick Summary

Those two attributes are used by the [inspect.signature()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) function to retrieve metadata about a function or method's call signature.

### Real-world Application

One use case for manually specifying one of these attributes is to provide useful tooltips for a function that uses `*args`.

In this example, the [randrange()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) method uses `*args` to accept a variable number of inputs.  However, we want the signature provided to *help()* and tooltips to show the meaning of each argument so that it matches the corresponding [*range()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) function.

```
import random

class Random(random.Random):
    
    def randrange(self, /, *args):
        'Choose a random value from range(start[, stop[, step]]).'
        return self.choice(range(*args))

    randrange.__text_signature__ = '($self, start, stop=None, step=1, /)'
```

The `__text_signature__` attribute informs the creation of the *Signature* object:

```
>>> inspect.signature(Random.randrange)
<Signature (self, start, stop=None, step=1, /)>
```

This makes the *help()* output more useful:

```
>>> help(Random.randrange)
Help on function randrange in module __main__:

randrange(self, start, stop=None, step=1, /)
    Choose a random value from range(start[, stop[, step]]).
```