# Getting parameter names for __future__ functions in python

Tags: python

My 2.7.5 version of `__future__.print_function` doesn't allow use of the `new` argument:

```
>>> print('hi', end='')
Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 1)
```

I'll ask about why this is in a separate post if I can't figure that out. For now, I wanted to see what arguments were available in my environment's version of this function.

I looked at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218616/getting-method-parameter-names-in-python) and some related ones, but these do not seem to work when I try:

```
>>> print.func_code.co_varnames
Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 1)
>>> print_function.func_code.co_varnames
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: _Feature instance has no attribute 'func_code'
```

I'm guessing that the special nature of `__future__` functions is why this standard technique fails.

Is there another way to check what args my version `__future__.print_function` takes?

Comment: What REPL are you using that gives a parsing error there?

Comment: Also, `print()` in 3.x doesn't support `new` either.

Comment: thx. that's consistent w/Martijn's info. not sure what "REPL" is but this is Python 2.7.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to treat a built-in function (implemented in C) as a user-defined function. They are not the same thing.  `.func_code` is only defined for user-defined functions (implemented in Python).

The [`__future__` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) only holds metadata about features, the `__future__.print_function` object is not the same object as the `print()` function. Instead, the object tells you more about what version of Python first supported the feature, and in what version the feature becomes mandatory (and the `from __future__` import becomes a no-op), as well as a bitfield flag for the `compile()` function:

```
>>> import __future__
>>> __future__.print_function
_Feature((2, 6, 0, 'alpha', 2), (3, 0, 0, 'alpha', 0), 65536)
>>> __future__.print_function.optional
(2, 6, 0, 'alpha', 2)
>>> __future__.print_function.mandatory
(3, 0, 0, 'alpha', 0)
>>> __future__.print_function.compiler_flag
65536
```

In Python 2.7, built-in function objects such as `print()` simply do not have enough information for you to discover what arguments they support. In Python 3, this is slowly changing as [more and more built-in types are given metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847035/what-are-signature-and-text-signature-used-for-in-python-3-4), but the `print()` function is not yet among them:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.signature(print)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mpietre/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.4/inspect.py", line 2045, in signature
    return _signature_internal(obj)
  File "/Users/mpietre/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.4/inspect.py", line 1947, in _signature_internal
    skip_bound_arg=skip_bound_arg)
  File "/Users/mpietre/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.4/inspect.py", line 1884, in _signature_from_builtin
    raise ValueError("no signature found for builtin {!r}".format(func))
ValueError: no signature found for builtin <built-in function print>
```

I'm not sure where you got the idea from that `new` is a valid keyword for `print()` in *any* Python version however. No version of Python exists that supports that argument.

The only argument that is missing from `print()` in Python 2 and present in Python 3.3 and up, is the `flush` argument, see the [Python 3 docs for `print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

> [...] if the *flush* keyword argument is true, the stream is forcibly flushed.
>
> *Changed in version 3.3*: Added the *flush* keyword argument.

The only way to test for that (other than testing with `sys.version_info >= (3, 3)`) is to try and use it:

```
from io import StringIO

try:
    print('', end='', flush=False, file=StringIO())
    print_supports_flush = True
except TypeError:
    print_supports_flush = False
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for all that background on __future__ functions...I got the "new" argument from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space. Did I misunderstand that?

Comment: @Roland: I think you did; there is no mention of a `new` argument there, just that the `print()` function is new.

Comment: hmm, I was looking at the 3rd example in CodeLogic's answer. It's talking about Python 3.x (which could be my problem).

Comment: Yet none of his examples use a `new` argument. His last example does use `flush` which is Python 3.3 and up only.

Comment: what about `print('.', end="")`? It's just before the `flush` example.

Comment: @Roland: but that's not `new`, that's `end`. Note that I use backticks for *code*, not emphasis. And all versions of the `print()` function (Python 2.6+ and up) support the `end` argument.

Comment: @Roland: your question used `new` as an argument, not as an adjective.