# How to get the signature parameters of a callable, or reliably determine when this is not possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The built-in `int` takes two parameters:

```
>>> print(int.__doc__)
int(x=0) -> integer
int(x, base=10) -> integer

Convert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments
...
```

However, (in CPython 3.4.0) `inspect.signature` shows 0:

```
>>> len(inspect.signature(int).parameters)
0
```

in contrast with a user-defined function:

```
>>> def my_int(x, base=10):
...     return int(x, base)
... 
>>> len(inspect.signature(my_int).parameters)
2
```

The [docs for `inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) do say:

> Some callables may not be introspectable in certain implementations of Python. For example, in CPython, some built-in functions defined in C provide no metadata about their arguments.

But they also say:

> Raises ValueError if no signature can be provided, and TypeError if that type of object is not supported.

So I am surprised that I did not get a `ValueError` and instead got what appears to be an incorrect signature.

Is there a way to reliably (and programmatically) determine when it is not possible to get the parameters for a callable with `inspect`? That is, if I am given something like `int`, is there a way to distinguish between "this thing does not have any parameters" and "it is not possible to determine what parameters this thing has"?

Comment: Maybe this will help: [What are `__signature__` and `__text_signature__` used for in Python 3.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847035/what-are-signature-and-text-signature-used-for-in-python-3-4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an open bug report for this:  http://bugs.python.org/issue23934

The problem is that if the obj passed to `signature()` is a 'type', and it doesn't have a user defined **init** or **new**, it just gives up and returns the signature for `object`, which has 0 parameters.

If the obj is in the builtins module, and it's a 'type', but not an Exception, there's a pretty good chance it's not going to work with `signature()`.

I came up with this workaround to find the problem objs... It's not particularly elegant, but it may be useful to you:

```
def count_params():
    output = {}
    for funcname in dir(builtins):
        f = getattr( builtins,funcname)
        if isinstance(f, type):
            try:
                paramcount = len(inspect.signature(f).parameters)
                output[funcname] = paramcount
            except:
                pass
                #print("%s is a %s" % (funcname, type(f)))
    return output
```

Output:

```
{'__loader__': 0,
 'bool': 0,
 'bytes': 0,
 'complex': 0,
 'enumerate': 0,
 'filter': 0,
 'float': 0,
 'frozenset': 0,
 'int': 0,
 'map': 0,
 'memoryview': 0,
 'object': 0,
 'range': 0,
 'reversed': 0,
 'slice': 0,
 'str': 0,
 'tuple': 0,
 'zip': 0}
```

Comment: Thanks for the bug link.  There's also the issue of subclasses of these types. For example, `inspect.signature` incorrectly returns an empty signature for any subclass of `int` that does not define its own `__init__`. (If the subclass defines its own `__init__` then the correct signature is returned.) @user1941126's (deleted) answer actually suggests a pretty good augmentation to your answer: if the callable has 0 parameters and is a type, then check the signature of `__init__`. If `__init__` has more than 1 parameter then something fishy is going on.