# How to retrieve/know function's default values

Tags: python, function, default-value

I am a python beginner and I currently struggle with some (probably quite simple) stuff. I would like to know the default parameters of a python function, more specifically of `cv2.ORB_create()`.

With the following code I managed to see the 'documentation string':

```
import cv2
orb = cv2.ORB_create()
print(cv2.ORB_create.__doc__)
```

However, `print(cv2.ORB_create.__defaults__)` just gives me an error;

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__defaults__'
```

Maybe I am missing a link between functions, modules, etc. but I am really stuck...

Since the concern was brought up that this is a duplicate. I also tried `inspect.signature` and by extension `inspect.getargspec`, but this give me another error `ValueError: no signature found for builtin <built-in function ORB_create>`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that `inspect.signature` and by extension `inspect.getargspec` also failed. So the other answers do not / did not help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cv2.ORB_create()` seems to be a function written with the Python extensions (In C instead of Python). As such, it isn't a "normal" function object, and there is no way to see the default values reliably (As it is handled manually in C).

One possible solution would be to look at the `__text_signature__` attribute, but this may not be reliable. See [What are __signature__ and __text_signature__ used for in Python 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25847035/5754656).

Comment: Thanks, that explains my issue. Unfortunatelly, `__text_signature__` returns None. But I will have a closer look at you link.