# How exactly does inspect.signature work with classes?

Tags: python, class, signature

The [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) doc states that it supports classes as input, but it doesn't go into any sort of detail:

> Accepts a wide range of Python callables, from plain functions and classes to `functools.partial()` objects.

If I call `inspect.signature(MyClass)`, what signature does it return? Does it return the signature of `MyClass.__init__`? Or `MyClass.__new__`? Or something else?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It tries pretty much everything it reasonably could. I think the details are probably deliberately undocumented, because they're complicated and likely to get more so as new Python versions add more stuff to try.

For example, as of CPython 3.7.3, the [code path](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Lib/inspect.py#L2299) tries the following things in order:

- If the metaclass has a custom `__call__` defined in Python, it uses the signature of the metaclass `__call__` with the first argument removed.
- Otherwise, if the class has a `__new__` method defined in Python, it uses the `__new__` signature with the first argument removed.
- Otherwise, if the class has an `__init__` method defined in Python, it uses the `__init__` signature with the first argument removed.
- Otherwise, it traverses the MRO looking for a [`__text_signature__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847035/what-are-signature-and-text-signature-used-for-in-python-3-4). If it finds one, it parses `__text_signature__` to get the signature information.
- If it still hasn't found anything, if the type's `__init__` is `object.__init__` and the type's `__new__` is `object.__new__`, it returns the signature of the `object` class. (There's a misleading comment and a possible bug involving metaclasses around this point - the comment says it's going to check for `type.__init__`, but it doesn't do that. I think [this commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/2623c8c23cead505a78ec416072223552e94727e#diff-8fb5d890c8ae80e19883adc7fbdd2c8fL1884) may have made a mistake here.)
- If it still hasn't found anything, it gives up and raises a `ValueError` saying it couldn't find anything.

Comment: Hah, it actually chops off the first argument of the metaclass's `__call__` even if it's decorated with `@staticmethod`. Nice subtle bug.