# Why does `math.log` not have a `__text_signature__` in Python?

Tags: python

I was playing around in the Python REPL and I noticed most `math` functions have the `__text_signature__` attribute; I notice it provides information regarding function signatures, and is non-None for every function in the `math` module (this is Python 3.11) except the `log` function and the `hypot` function.

```py
>>> print(math.log.__text_signature__)
None
>>> math.exp.__text_signature__
'($module, x, /)'
```

Is there a reason for this? It seems pretty random to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are \_\_signature\_\_ and \_\_text\_signature\_\_ used for in Python 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847035/what-are-signature-and-text-signature-used-for-in-python-3-4)

Comment: Not really, it's super helpful for me to understand what the `__text_signature__` is, but doesn't really help me understand why these specific functions don't have it. Thank you though!

Comment: In the function `math_log` in the module `mathlib.c` is a comment: `/* AC: cannot convert yet, see gh-102839 and gh-89381, waiting
   for support of multiple signatures */`.
See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/mathmodule.c

Comment: @YuriGinsburg Seems to be it, thank you! Could you put this in an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: That was somewhat implied by the "potential dupe" which explains where the __text_signature__ comes from, so you can look up the original source =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the source code of module `mathlib.c` function `math_log` has a comment

```
/* AC: cannot convert yet, see gh-102839 and gh-89381, waiting
   for support of multiple signatures */
```