# How to generate .pyi files for a compiled Python extension?

Tags: python, mypy, python-extensions, typeshed

I build a compiled Python extension (`.pyd` file) with C++ and `pybind11`. I would like to generate a single Python interface `.pyi` file for my `.pyd` file.

There are a few similar questions referring to the `mypy` `stubgen` module, however, this one produces a `UnicodeError` trying to run `stubgen Dummy` where `Dummy` is `Dummy.pyd` file:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2: invalid start byte`

Another project, [make-stub-files](https://github.com/edreamleo/make-stub-files) does not work with `.pyd` files at all, giving the `('not a python file'` error.

Are there any tools that could let me generate .pyi files either from the source `.cpp` files or from compiled `.pyd` files?

The issue is registered in the [`mypy` GitHub repository](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5283).

Comment: See also (no answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49409249/python-generate-function-stubs-from-c-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [issue was registered in the `mypy` GitHub source repository](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5283) and fixed in a [pull request](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/5284).

The reason for the issue was that when `mypy` was trying to figure out whether a given module is a Python extension it checked for the `.so` file extension used on Linux, but did not check for the `.pyd` file extension used on Windows.