# How to get parameter hints in VSCode for pyd files in general and confluent_kafka specifically?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, parameters, confluent-kafka-python

I am new to kafka, and trying work some basic examples via **VScode**. The problem is I can't seem to make parameter hints work at all for all the artefacts imported via `confluent_kafka`. The module itself is a wrapper, and I was wondering if there was a way to get parameter hinting the same way other python classes and modules work?

[image]

Comment: Unclear what you mean "wrapper". The source code still has defined annotations and parameters that should show in the IDE

Comment: @OneCricketeer, the `Producer` is made with C, but interpreted (converted?) with `.cimpl`, as shown in the repo here : https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/src/confluent_kafka/__init__.py

Comment: Maybe I've only used Pycharm, where I think it does work

Comment: See feature request [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/166)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible. Because what you want was stored in the file of `cimpl.cp39-win_amd64.pyd`.

The Language Server can not provide Intellisense from the file with `pyd` filename extension.

You can have a look at the `cimply` with PyCharm, as it can decompilation it.

Comment: According to @OneCricketeer pycharm can do it. Any idea what aspect of pycharm is different in this regard? How can decompilation point towards the function parameters in python?

Comment: @Imad Yes the PyCharm can do it, but the Language Server of python in the VSCode has not this ability. I had submitted a feature request on GitHub, you can refer to [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1711)

Comment: @Imad Does this help? If you have any doubt about it, feel free to let me know.

Comment: thanks for your efforts, although the feature request was shut down really fast... I wonder what elements should be taken into account to create a VS Extension

Comment: @Imad This feature seems to need to be combined with the related Language Server and the Python Extension.

Comment: It's a bummer. I hope they will implement this ability in the future anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is not supported by VScode. One way to get the tooltips is to create a `.pyi` file for your package which defines the interface the functions. If you ship this with the package (or have this file in your VSCode working directory) it will be able to give parameter hints and such!

You can create one using `mypy`'s `stubgen`, but it does not automatically include the docstrings. You can write one yourself however. Have a look here: [Python: Generate function stubs from C module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49409249/python-generate-function-stubs-from-c-module)