# Enable Visual Studio Intellisense for .pyd python modules generated with pybind11

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, intellisense, pybind11

**Background**:  I've successfully used pybind11 in a Visual Studio 2022 MSBuild project to create a .pyd library of C/C++ functions which can be imported into python code directly using the instructions here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

**Problem**:  Intellisense in VS2022 doesn't seem to recognize the imported module contents and display the expected autocomplete pop-ups or hints about exported functions/symbols/signatures/etc when coding in a .py file which imports this .pyd library.  Intellisense *does* seem to know the library *exists* (i.e. no warning/error squiggles under the import directive).

**Question**:  Is it possible to enable Intellisense to provide details about the imported module like it would when importing a .py file?  Either via some configuration flags or additional content added to the `PYBIND11_MODULE(){}` section of the C/C++ code?

(Note this was not with Visual Studio Code or a CMake project, but I would be interested if this common problem exists for those tools in case the fix is similar. [This discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7736#issuecomment-537620794) is along similar lines, but relevant VSCode and mentions something called pydoc which doesn't come up in the instructions linked above from Microsoft.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68883854/how-to-get-parameter-hints-in-vscode-for-pyd-files-in-general-and-confluent-kafk