# Python Intellisense Documentation for C/C++ Extension

Tags: python, c, visual-studio-code

I have a simple example c extension for Python (CPython 3.9), based on [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41245451/10565721). I can access this from python via the function `help(_myexample)`, but the question is: Is there a way to display the docstring (foo_doc) on hover, such as provided by Microsoft's Python extension for vscode for standard Python docstrings?

```c
static PyObject* foo(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {

    /* blabla [...] */

}

PyDoc_STRVAR(
    foo_doc,
    "foo(timeout, flags=None, /)\n"
    "--\n"
    "\n"
    "Great example function\n"
    "Arguments: (timeout, flags=None)\n"
    "Doc blahblah doc doc doc.");

static PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    {"foo", foo, METH_VARARGS, foo_doc},
    {NULL},
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC init_myexample(void) {
    (void) Py_InitModule3("_myexample", methods, "a simple example module");
}
```

Hover feature referred to above:
[image]

Comment: if you can read that image you have very good eyesight

Comment: do you use a Python wrapper to interface to the C functions, if you put the doc strings there